# Безопасность eval()

Tags: php

В `php` шаблоне прописан следующий код:

```
function langs($a) {
 $type_lang = $_GET['lang'];

 eval(file_get_contents("system/langs/$type_lang.txt"));
 return $worlds[$a];
}
```

Может он быть опасен чем-либо?

Comment: Неплохо бы проверять, что такой файл существует, и что `$type_lang` состоит только из букв и цифр.

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасибо! Условия уже написал :)

Comment: А зачем eval в данной ситуации, почему не использовать include ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может. Если злодей в курсе устройства, и может как-то загрузить текстовый файл на сервер, пусть, в другую папку, то вызовом `shablon.php?lang=../../uploads/evil.txt` выполниться его код.

Comment: Но в данном случае я поставил условие, мол если lang != rus или eng, то работа завершается...

Comment: Я ответил на исходный вопрос. Если допускаете только один из жестко прописанных вариантов, наверное, уже не так страшно. Но все же использование `eval()` для загрузки языковых строк — не самое лучшее решение.

Answer (score 3):

А уверены ли вы, что в вашей системе нету и никогда не появится дырок позволяющих что то написать в этот самый $[type_lang.txt](http://type_lang.txt)?

Если это произойдет, ваш скрипт тут же превратится в шелл.

Вывод: eval безопасен только со статичным кодом внутри

Comment: А например какие дыры могут быть? Я вроде не предоставляю возможность записывать туда что-то и сам делаю это вручную..

Comment: "вроде". У меня железное правило - относись к своему коду так, как будто его будет использовать твой злейший враг.